# Drag and drop components with in the same container using EXTJS 4

Tags: drag-and-drop, extjs4.1

I have created a container which contains 20 components in it. Each of the component is created through xtype: 'component'. I want to be able to drag and drop each component at any location with in the container and the end result result should be something like swapping between components. The component data is stored in the database along with X and Y co-ordinates (not actual page pointers)
EX: Say container has 2 columns and 10 rows, each row is again a container containing two components in it with X and Y co-ordinates as X=0,Y=0 and X=1,Y=0 and so on.

How can I achieve drag and drop functionality for this? I should be able to obtain X and Y co-ordinates for the component that is dragged and the X and Y co-ordinates of the component that this component will be dropped.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: are you using senchas drag and drop or html5 drag and drop?

Comment: I am using sencha's drag and drop: Ext.dd.DragZone and Ext.dd.DropZone

Comment: So you want a type of dragging dashboard that change the order of the components?

Comment: Yes, any idea on how this can be done through use of onNodeDrop() function? or any code sample?

Comment: I tried that using floating components exacly over the other components

Comment: Too much code to low speed effective execution

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a sortable plugin created with HTML 5 d&D to make dragging a dashboard

here is a simple fiddle
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1kuo

Here is the plugin which i'm using:

https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable

thanks to RubaXa and to other workers